# Poco Net HTTPSClientSession Host not found

Tags: https

We have a client application which keeps sending some plain text to the server every 5 seconds.

Every 5 seconds, we create a HTTPSClientSession with server IP and Port, and then send the data. Session is closed afer send as HTTPSClientSession is created as a local variable in the sending function.

What we have observed is that in some cases, sending data works for some time and after that it stops working.

Strange thing is that if we disable wifi and enable it again, client resumes sending data.

Any help about how to solve this is appreciated.

Most of the times POCO exception returns "Host not found" , "Timeout" or "Software caused connection abort".

Thanks

Comment: We are also seeing the exact same thing in our application. We do also create (and destroy) many HTTPSClientSessions - and after a while some customers gets a "Host not found" and/or "Timeout" Poco::Exception. Running 1.9.1. Will investigate it further and try to reproduce.